# Извлечение href при помощи grab

Tags: python, grab

Как извлечь ссылку из поисковой выдачи яндекса при помощи grab?
Делаю, как в документации:

```
link=g.doc.tree.xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/ul/li[1]/div/div[2]/a/@href').text()
```

Выдает ошибку *AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'* , т.к. без `.text()` это просто пустой массив.

Использую grab последней версии 0.6.21.

Comment: Как насчёт попробовать написать более вменяемый XPath и попутно проверить его в браузере?

Comment: @andreymal А чем этот плох? Если покороче, как в доках, `//a[@class="b-serp-item__title-link"]/@href` - та же ошибка. Вытащил из firebug же, с другими сайтами для извлечения текста вполне работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, [у списков конечно же не существует никакого метода text()](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists).

Во-вторых, раз возвращается пустой список, значит ни один элемент не соответствует введённому XPath и надо с ним играться.

Исходники страницы яндекса какие-то сложные и запутанные, и лучшее, что я натыкал — это вот:

```
g.doc.tree.xpath('//a[contains(@class, "serp-item__title-link")]//@href')
```

Но сие захватывает много мусорных рекламных ссылок, но надёжного способа их отсеять я как-то пока не увидел, впрочем, не по теме вопроса это уже.

В-третьих, приведённый в вопросе XPath плох тем, что очень сильно привязывается к структуре документа: даже если бы он и работал, то он перестал бы работать сразу после того, как Яндексу, например, приспичит добавить ещё один рекламный блок, сместив тем самым другие блоки и сбив их нумерацию.

Comment: Спасибо, заработало. 
Впрочем, довольно непонятно, как это всё работает и почему нужно делать именно так.

Comment: Документацию по синтаксису XPath нетрудно нагуглить. А contains я тут использовал потому, что XPath не различает классы по отдельности и рядом с этим классом могут быть прописаны какие-нибудь ещё классы (из-за этого вариант из комментариев к вопросу и не работает)